# MySQL Tables Require Daily Repairs - Server, Table or HD?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I've been experiencing a weird issue with one of MySQL DBs. Every day, sometimes 2-3 times per day, I'll need to repair the tables. The MySQL DB has 25 tables with 5.6m rows in total.

The bigger ones are:

```
Table A - 599k rows / 867MB
Table B - 2.1m rows / 146MB
Table C - 2.2m rows / 520MB
```

It seems table C needs to be repaired pretty frequently, Tables A & B not as much.

When the table needs to be repaired, I'm not seeing it being marked as crashed or in use. But through other tools, I can see the data is not what it should be.

When I do repair the table, I'll see a message similar to:

```
[table c] repair info Wrong bytesec:  54-55-102 at 368251940; Skipped
[table c] repair warning Number of rows changed from 2127934 to 2127931
```

or

```
[table c] repair info Wrong bytesec:  171-30-101 at 341237312; Skipped
[table c] repair warning Number of rows changed from 1984585 to 1984582
```

I've tried making adjustments in my.cnf but no difference.

The server is a cloud server running both MySQL and Apache. Plenty of space available on all HDs:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2             99G   14G   80G  15% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1             97M   49M   44M  53% /boot
/dev/xvdc1            296G   25G  257G   9% /data
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the cloud HD, the server or the tables themselves. The problem didn't start happening until about 2 months ago and the size of the DB has only changed by 300-400MB until now.

Any idea what I should be looking at to verify where the problem might be?

Using MySQL v5.1.66 and MyISAM

Thanks in advance.

Best, Cent

Comment: are you seeing anything in the error log?

Comment: From the mysql.log, I see these:

130418  8:44:41 [ERROR] Got error 134 when reading table './[table c]'
130418  9:20:37 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Table '[table c]' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130418  9:20:37 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
130418 10:04:38 [ERROR] Got error 134 when reading table './[table c]'
130418 11:08:40 [ERROR] Got error 127 when reading table './[table c]'
130418 12:30:05 [Note] Found 2127931 of 2127934 rows when repairing './[table c]'

Comment: I know the 134 error is a corrupt table.  127 seems like an error reading the table.

The problem happens when there's a lot of web traffic or very little.  Sometimes a table will go corrupt, i'll fix it and it will get corrupt 20 mins later.  Sometimes after repairing a table, it will be fine for 10-20 hrs.  No specific reason that I can see.

I'm wondering if it might be bad sectors on the cloud server HD but hoping these issues ring a bell with someone that may have had a similar problem.

Comment: Have you any other kind of software running on this server that read the mysql files... like an antivirus or similar?

Comment: Why use MyISAM - it is known to corrupt your data. Using InnoDB is a much better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You should get away from MyISAM as soon as possible. Why ???

- MyISAM caches only index pages in the Key Buffer
- InnoDB caches Data Pages and Index Pages in the InnoDB Buffer Pool

I have mentioned this many times before

- `May 06, 2013` : [MySQL high CPU usage (MyISAM table indexes)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/mysql-high-cpu-usage-myisam-table-indexes/41636#41636)
- `Apr 08, 2013` : [If MySQL isn't caching, then what is?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39521/if-mysql-isnt-caching-then-what-is/39523#39523)
- `Sep 26, 2012` : [Choosing MyISAM over InnoDB for these project requirements; and long term options](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24951/choosing-myisam-over-innodb-for-these-project-requirements-and-long-term-option/24968#24968)
- `Oct 07, 2011` : [Should I use a storage engine other than MyISAM to optimise these tables or should I get better disks?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/should-i-use-a-storage-engine-other-than-myisam-to-optimise-these-tables-or-shou/6615#6615)
- `Apr 04, 2011` : [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)

This is very critical because data pages must rely solely on the OS for cached writes to the `.MYD` of a MyISAM table. In a highly trafficked website, the OS will experience a glut in memory with swapping as a consequence and foregone conclusion. An OS crash or a mysqld crash  will yield corrupt MyISAM tables for every MyISAM table that was open and not fully flushed.   A crashed MyISAM table could simply be just a bad open file count in it header. In other case, it could be incomplete writes to the `.MYD` file. In the two repair messages in the question, you lost three row both times.

IMHO this problem is very apparent when running MySQL in Windows (Imagine : Windows handling disk writes ???) and no less different for Linux. MyISAM will suffer just the same.

I highly recommend three(3) things:

- Switch to InnoDB
- Increase installed RAM
- Configure as much buffer pool as possible

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus or "Non-Conventional" Backup software has also often caused corruption.

Your first step is to try to find out what is changing the MySQL files.

Countinuous table repairing can only be a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

what is frequently crushed in myisam table is it's index which you can see under database path as table_name.MYI , mysql use key_buffer_size to cache the myisam index .
sometime when key_buffer_size is not sufficient, mysql can not load the whole needed part of index ,so table  will be crushed , i think as first step you need to increase this buffer ,and be sure that you have sufficient RAM before change it 
find more details about key_buffuer_size in this link 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size