# MySQL - high CPU usage (MyISAM tables)

Tags: mysql, myisam

We have a server running LAMP stack on CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
MySQL is having high CPU usage constantly which causes server to lag as shown

```
top - 13:50:47 up 80 days, 13:53,  1 user,  load average: 4.02, 3.44, 3.19
Tasks: 129 total,   2 running, 127 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  : 24.7%us, 19.8%sy,  0.2%ni, 54.5%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 23.0%us,  9.4%sy,  0.1%ni, 67.0%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4034120k total,  3317400k used,   716720k free,   124324k buffers
Swap:  8385920k total,     9788k used,  8376132k free,  2004692k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
26266 mysql     15   0 2472m 464m 4448 S 158.6 11.8 109:00.59 mysqld
30276 apache    16   0  310m  16m 3724 S 12.1  0.4   0:00.85 httpd
30205 apache    16   0  309m  17m 3860 S  8.6  0.4   0:01.81 httpd
```

The server has 4GB RAM, tables are stored in MyISAM. 
Database is about 6665MB. It has a replicated database (readonly) on another server

MySQL version:

```
 +----------------+
 | 5.1.57-ius-log |
 +----------------+
```

Here's our my.cnf (IP information Xed out).

`[mysqld]
# General
datadir             = /home/mysql
tmpdir                          = /var/lib/mysqltmp
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking           = 1
skip-name-resolve
open-files-limit                = 20000
# Cache
thread-cache-size               = 16
table-open-cache                = 2048
table-definition-cache          = 512
query-cache-size                = 32M 
query-cache-limit               = 1M
# Per-thread Buffers
sort-buffer-size                = 1M
read-buffer-size                = 1M
read-rnd-buffer-size            = 8M
join-buffer-size                = 1M
# Temp Tables
tmp-table-size                  = 64M 
max-heap-table-size             = 64M 
# Networking
back-log                        = 100
max-connections                 = 200
max-connect-errors              = 10000
max-allowed-packet              = 16M
interactive-timeout             = 600
wait-timeout                    = 600
#Storage Engines
innodb                          = FORCE
# MyISAM
key-buffer-size                 = 64M 
myisam-sort-buffer-size         = 128M
# InnoDB
innodb-buffer-pool-size         = 16M
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb-log-buffer-size          = 4M
# Replication
server-id                       = 1
bind-address            = XX.XX.XXX.XXX
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysqllogs/bin-log
binlog-do-db            = rewards1
binlog-ignore-db        = mysql
relay-log-index=master-relay-bin.index
relay-log                      = /var/lib/mysqllogs/relay-log
#Logging
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/slow-log
#MysqlTuner
skip-innodb
max_connections = 200
wait_timeout = 500
interactive_timeout = 500
query_cache_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 5M
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
table_cache = 4096
key_buffer_size = 2048M
[mysqld_safe]
log-error                       = /var/log/mysqld.log`

We've seen similar problem as described in 
[MySQL high CPU usage (MyISAM table indexes)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/mysql-high-cpu-usage-myisam-table-indexes)
which I've adjust the key_buffer_size to 2048M so it's greater than MyISAM index

`mysql> sELECT SUM(index_length) ndxsize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM';
+------------+
| ndxsize    |
+------------+
| 1876895744 |
+------------+`

MySQL continues to have high %CPU, our system admin suggested that we add more RAM to the box, will this solve the problem?

Any helps/suggestions are appreciated!!

## Thank you!!!

Edited for show status, 
it seems that show status only shows session status, changed it to run global status

`mysql> show global status;
+--------------------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name                  | Value        |
+--------------------------------+--------------+
| Aborted_clients                | 15           |
| Aborted_connects               | 101          |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use          | 0            |
| Binlog_cache_use               | 0            |
| Bytes_received                 | 4820268802   |
| Bytes_sent                     | 104046088856 |
| Com_admin_commands             | 2            |
| Com_assign_to_keycache         | 0            |
| Com_alter_db                   | 0            |
| Com_alter_db_upgrade           | 0            |
| Com_alter_event                | 0            |
| Com_alter_function             | 0            |
| Com_alter_procedure            | 0            |
| Com_alter_server               | 0            |
| Com_alter_table                | 0            |
| Com_alter_tablespace           | 0            |
| Com_analyze                    | 0            |
| Com_backup_table               | 0            |
| Com_begin                      | 0            |
| Com_binlog                     | 0            |
| Com_call_procedure             | 0            |
| Com_change_db                  | 1376751      |
| Com_change_master              | 0            |
| Com_check                      | 0            |
| Com_checksum                   | 2            |
| Com_commit                     | 0            |
| Com_create_db                  | 0            |
| Com_create_event               | 0            |
| Com_create_function            | 0            |
| Com_create_index               | 1            |
| Com_create_procedure           | 0            |
| Com_create_server              | 0            |
| Com_create_table               | 133          |
| Com_create_trigger             | 0            |
| Com_create_udf                 | 0            |
| Com_create_user                | 0            |
| Com_create_view                | 0            |
| Com_dealloc_sql                | 0            |
| Com_delete                     | 31518        |
| Com_delete_multi               | 0            |
| Com_do                         | 0            |
| Com_drop_db                    | 0            |
| Com_drop_event                 | 0            |
| Com_drop_function              | 0            |
| Com_drop_index                 | 0            |
| Com_drop_procedure             | 0            |
| Com_drop_server                | 0            |
| Com_drop_table                 | 133          |
| Com_drop_trigger               | 0            |
| Com_drop_user                  | 0            |
| Com_drop_view                  | 0            |
| Com_empty_query                | 0            |
| Com_execute_sql                | 0            |
| Com_flush                      | 0            |
| Com_grant                      | 0            |
| Com_ha_close                   | 0            |
| Com_ha_open                    | 0            |
| Com_ha_read                    | 0            |
| Com_help                       | 0            |
| Com_insert                     | 140425       |
| Com_insert_select              | 137          |
| Com_install_plugin             | 0            |
| Com_kill                       | 0            |
| Com_load                       | 0            |
| Com_load_master_data           | 0            |
| Com_load_master_table          | 0            |
| Com_lock_tables                | 0            |
| Com_optimize                   | 0            |
| Com_preload_keys               | 0            |
| Com_prepare_sql                | 0            |
| Com_purge                      | 0            |
| Com_purge_before_date          | 0            |
| Com_release_savepoint          | 0            |
| Com_rename_table               | 0            |
| Com_rename_user                | 0            |
| Com_repair                     | 0            |
| Com_replace                    | 5805         |
| Com_replace_select             | 0            |
| Com_reset                      | 0            |
| Com_restore_table              | 0            |
| Com_revoke                     | 0            |
| Com_revoke_all                 | 0            |
| Com_rollback                   | 3391         |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint      | 0            |
| Com_savepoint                  | 0            |
| Com_select                     | 7088783      |
| Com_set_option                 | 1226039      |
| Com_show_authors               | 0            |
| Com_show_binlog_events         | 0            |
| Com_show_binlogs               | 0            |
| Com_show_charsets              | 0            |
| Com_show_collations            | 0            |
| Com_show_column_types          | 0            |
| Com_show_contributors          | 0            |
| Com_show_create_db             | 0            |
| Com_show_create_event          | 0            |
| Com_show_create_func           | 0            |
| Com_show_create_proc           | 0            |
| Com_show_create_table          | 2            |
| Com_show_create_trigger        | 0            |
| Com_show_databases             | 24           |
| Com_show_engine_logs           | 0            |
| Com_show_engine_mutex          | 0            |
| Com_show_engine_status         | 0            |
| Com_show_events                | 0            |
| Com_show_errors                | 0            |
| Com_show_fields                | 17299        |
| Com_show_function_status       | 0            |
| Com_show_grants                | 0            |
| Com_show_keys                  | 0            |
| Com_show_master_status         | 0            |
| Com_show_new_master            | 0            |
| Com_show_open_tables           | 0            |
| Com_show_plugins               | 0            |
| Com_show_privileges            | 0            |
| Com_show_procedure_status      | 0            |
| Com_show_processlist           | 131          |
| Com_show_profile               | 0            |
| Com_show_profiles              | 0            |
| Com_show_slave_hosts           | 0            |
| Com_show_slave_status          | 0            |
| Com_show_status                | 10990        |
| Com_show_storage_engines       | 0            |
| Com_show_table_status          | 13           |
| Com_show_tables                | 23           |
| Com_show_triggers              | 0            |
| Com_show_variables             | 3400         |
| Com_show_warnings              | 0            |
| Com_slave_start                | 0            |
| Com_slave_stop                 | 0            |
| Com_stmt_close                 | 0            |
| Com_stmt_execute               | 0            |
| Com_stmt_fetch                 | 0            |
| Com_stmt_prepare               | 0            |
| Com_stmt_reprepare             | 0            |
| Com_stmt_reset                 | 0            |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data        | 0            |
| Com_truncate                   | 133          |
| Com_uninstall_plugin           | 0            |
| Com_unlock_tables              | 0            |
| Com_update                     | 713677       |
| Com_update_multi               | 133          |
| Com_xa_commit                  | 0            |
| Com_xa_end                     | 0            |
| Com_xa_prepare                 | 0            |
| Com_xa_recover                 | 0            |
| Com_xa_rollback                | 0            |
| Com_xa_start                   | 0            |
| Compression                    | OFF          |
| Connections                    | 1381196      |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables        | 500962       |
| Created_tmp_files              | 17174        |
| Created_tmp_tables             | 1323921      |
| Delayed_errors                 | 0            |
| Delayed_insert_threads         | 0            |
| Delayed_writes                 | 0            |
| Flush_commands                 | 1            |
| Handler_commit                 | 0            |
| Handler_delete                 | 38013        |
| Handler_discover               | 0            |
| Handler_prepare                | 0            |
| Handler_read_first             | 326121       |
| Handler_read_key               | 141753461    |
| Handler_read_next              | 2628857102   |
| Handler_read_prev              | 65624374428  |
| Handler_read_rnd               | 55126444     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next          | 9990315545   |
| Handler_rollback               | 0            |
| Handler_savepoint              | 0            |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback     | 0            |
| Handler_update                 | 10330960     |
| Handler_write                  | 22915553     |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed         | 0            |
| Key_blocks_unused              | 1424358      |
| Key_blocks_used                | 297815       |
| Key_read_requests              | 3988011306   |
| Key_reads                      | 294476       |
| Key_write_requests             | 9047373      |
| Key_writes                     | 439479       |
| Last_query_cost                | 0.000000     |
| Max_used_connections           | 81           |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows       | 0            |
| Open_files                     | 1623         |
| Open_streams                   | 0            |
| Open_table_definitions         | 531          |
| Open_tables                    | 1093         |
| Opened_files                   | 2242361      |
| Opened_table_definitions       | 1076         |
| Opened_tables                  | 1655         |
| Prepared_stmt_count            | 0            |
| Qcache_free_blocks             | 10115        |
| Qcache_free_memory             | 36606896     |
| Qcache_hits                    | 6401379      |
| Qcache_inserts                 | 6086477      |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes           | 539333       |
| Qcache_not_cached              | 1001986      |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache        | 17468        |
| Qcache_total_blocks            | 45584        |
| Queries                        | 18400635     |
| Questions                      | 18400635     |
| Rpl_status                     | NULL         |
| Select_full_join               | 29962        |
| Select_full_range_join         | 0            |
| Select_range                   | 2141059      |
| Select_range_check             | 0            |
| Select_scan                    | 2084788      |
| Slave_open_temp_tables         | 0            |
| Slave_retried_transactions     | 0            |
| Slave_running                  | OFF          |
| Slow_launch_threads            | 4            |
| Slow_queries                   | 4            |
| Sort_merge_passes              | 8587         |
| Sort_range                     | 1924836      |
| Sort_rows                      | 117048520    |
| Sort_scan                      | 1366104      |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates        | 0            |
| Ssl_accepts                    | 0            |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits        | 0            |
| Ssl_cipher                     |              |
| Ssl_cipher_list                |              |
| Ssl_client_connects            | 0            |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates       | 0            |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth           | 0            |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode            | 0            |
| Ssl_default_timeout            | 0            |
| Ssl_finished_accepts           | 0            |
| Ssl_finished_connects          | 0            |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits         | 0            |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses       | 0            |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode         | NONE         |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows    | 0            |
| Ssl_session_cache_size         | 0            |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts     | 0            |
| Ssl_sessions_reused            | 0            |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries | 0            |
| Ssl_verify_depth               | 0            |
| Ssl_verify_mode                | 0            |
| Ssl_version                    |              |
| Table_locks_immediate          | 16998029     |
| Table_locks_waited             | 236687       |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used          | 0            |
| Tc_log_page_size               | 0            |
| Tc_log_page_waits              | 0            |
| Threads_cached                 | 10           |
| Threads_connected              | 7            |
| Threads_created                | 5861         |
| Threads_running                | 6            |
| Uptime                         | 250234       |
| Uptime_since_flush_status      | 250234       |
+--------------------------------+--------------+
249 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Show processlist during huge lag spike:

```
 mysql> show processlist;
 +---------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+--------------+-------+
 | Id      | User         | Host      | db       | Command | Time | State | Info                                                                                     |
 +---------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 1421036 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  478 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421054 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  478 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421084 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  474 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421188 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  456 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421296 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  435 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421298 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  435 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421334 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  430 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421335 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  430 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421342 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  426 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421405 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  415 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421459 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  409 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421494 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  404 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
 | 1421513 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |  399 |              | NULL                                                                                                |
```

## after mysql recovers

```
mysql> show processlist;
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id      | User         | Host      | db       | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 1423101 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
| 1427422 | rewards_user | localhost | rewards1 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL             |
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks again!! appreciated :)

Comment: Could you show the output of `SHOW STATUS` command from `mysql`?

Comment: Added the result for SHOW STATUS. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this `SHOW STATUS` was taken just after server restart? The server should be running for a while and serving normal requests before `SHOW STATUS` has good information.

Comment: I might have restarted mysql yesterday due to the heavy lag. How long should I wait till next mysql status measure?  Thanks!

Comment: A couple of hours shoule be enough.

Comment: Added the result for another SHOW STATUS. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the SHOW STATUS. Unfortunately I didn't notice anything odd there. I see that you have MySQL slow log enabled, (/var/log/slow-log). Does it have anything inside it? You could take a look at the queries there and see if they can be optimized.

Comment: Slow log only picked up about 3~5 slow queries everyday, that's why I suspect that it's not the primary cause of this. Can it be caused by a lot of small queries? if it's the case, is there any ways that I can verify this? will more RAM fix this? Thanks

Comment: Actually the `SHOW STATUS` looks quite odd. The numbers starting with Com_ are counts of different type of SQL queries the server has processed. According to this, only one SELECT query has been made, which doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Hi, this is definitely weird, I manually ran a checksum and a select query, and the com_checksum and com_select recorded them.

Comment: It seems that show status only shows the session status, I reran it with SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, updated the results in the post, good catch!

Comment: we just had another lag spike, I captured the SHOW PROCESSLIST, it seems to be similar issue described in  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/mysql-high-cpu-usage-myisam-table-indexes
I've added the SHOW PROCESSLIST; results to the post

Comment: on 2nd thought tho..the sleeping process could be caused by the constant cpu load, the cpu load stays high even after mysql recovered.

Comment: Sorry for the `SHOW STATUS` / `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` mixup. Your `handler_read_*` values are quite high. This indicates that your queries cause lots of table scans. This can be fixed by proper indexing of columns.